# Standalone components; dependency injection

Tags: angular

With modules, we've defined providers in the module and those would get registered on the module level.

If I understand correctly, the way to organize DI/providers with standalone components is by using `providers` in route definitions.

So, if we previously had a module that loaded under the route `/moduleA` and module itself had different services registered in `providers`, then with the new approach we would have same array of `providers` defined for the route `/moduleA` and all its children routes.

Is that correct statement?

And, if that's true, when to put providers into some `route` definition and when to standalone component `providers` array?

Comment: Have you seen this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3iSADIqLp2E ?

Comment: @NgDaddy I have not. Thank you for sharing. Will watch right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct. You can still [provide](https://angular.dev/guide/di/dependency-injection#providing-dependency):

- Services needed by your whole app [in `root`](https://angular.dev/guide/di/dependency-injection#preferred-at-the-application-root-level-using-providedin) (think `HttpClient`)

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {}
```

- Services needed by a group of components [in `NgModule.providers`](https://angular.dev/guide/ngmodules/providers#providedin-and-ngmodules) (shared state by module)

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [SomeComponentThatDependsOnMyService],
  providers: [MyService]
})
export class MyFeatureModule {}
```

- Services needed by a group of components [in `Route.providers`](https://angular.dev/api/router/Route#providers) (shared state by route)

```js
const featureRoutes = [
  { 
    path: '',
    children: [
      { path: 'a', loadComponent: () => import('./a.component.ts').then(c => c.AComponent) },
      { path: 'b', loadComponent: () => import('./b.component.ts').then(c => c.BComponent) },
    ],
    providers: [MyService]
  },
] as Routes;

const appRoutes = [
  { 
    path: 'feature',
    loadChildren: () => featureRoutes,
    providers: [MyOtherService]
  },
  { path: '**', component: NonFeatureComponent },
] as Routes;

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(appRoutes)
  ]
});
```

- Services needed by a single component [in `Component.providers`](https://angular.dev/guide/di/dependency-injection#at-the-component-level) (think instance state)

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-isolated',
  standalone: true,
  providers: [MyService]
})
export class MyIsolatedComponent {}
```

There is [a hierarchy](https://angular.dev/guide/di/hierarchical-dependency-injection) to where these services are provided and the "correct" place to provide a given service depends on factors including:

1. How many components or other services need to share the same instance of your service
2. How many components or other services should even know about your service
3. When your service should actually be instantiated (is it needed at application startup or only after a certain route/component has been loaded?)

But using `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })` is [still the preferred method](https://angular.dev/guide/di/dependency-injection#preferred-at-the-application-root-level-using-providedin) of providing a service because it allows for tree shaking services that are not used. I'd wager that what you're suggesting, `Route.providers` in a lazy-loaded route (`loadComponent()` or `loadChildren(Routes)`), is the second preference but the documentation does not make that explicit.

Comment: I wish I could give you 50 points for this. What a nice, systematic & concise answer! Just one thing that I am not clear about...since we map modules to routes (route `/products/` usually maps to `Products` module) what is the difference between shared state by module and shared state by route? I guess former is for the case when we mix modules with standalone components while latter is what we use when going with standalone components only. Is that fair assessment?

Comment: That’s correct! It’s still possible to scope by module, but the trend of the framework as a whole is to prefer standalone components and services. Modules are still supported, but root/route/component scoped services are the currently favored provisions.

Comment: one follow up question that just came to me: is there any difference between shared state by route and service registered in components providers in a case when that component is being loaded by the route? In other words, when that is the root component for the route. Any thoughts around that?

Comment: I believe that a service registered in a standalone component's `providers` array is only available to that component (and only that instance of that component even more specifically). Meaning if you have the same service registered at the route level and in the root component's `providers` array, the children of the root component will use the instance of the service provided at the route level. I'm not positive on that - I'd have to make a sample app to check. Either way, I wouldn't register a service on a component if I wanted to use it in any other component. I'd prefer the route level.

Comment: oh, you're right. although service registered in parent component is available to all of its children, lifetime is bound to parent component lifetime. that's a great point, forgot about it! thanks.

Comment: one more follow up...what is the lifetime of route providers? do they get destroyed when roite is not active anymore or is their lifetime same as app lifetime but just scope being limited to the route? i cant find that specifoc detail in docs. do you maybe know?

Comment: I'm not sure - that would make a good question on its own! I'll try to play around with it soon.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77902034/what-is-the-lifetime-of-route-providers/77902431?noredirect=1#comment137350031_77902431