# What is the lifetime of route providers?

Tags: angular

So, with standalone components, we get an option to put services into route `providers`.

I cannot find it in docs - what is the lifetime of those services instances?

Do they get destroyed when route is not active and recreated once active again or is their lifetime same as application lifetime?

Answer (score 1):

The route providers are used to setup a new EnvironmentInjector for this Route and use it for this Route and its children.

Once it is created, it won't be destroyed until the parent `EnvironmentInjector` is destroyed (mostly when the apps gets destroyed).

Comment: this calls for the question: mostly, except for when? :)

Comment: Main take on this, consider that they are not destroyed.

Comment: Is it related to how lazy loaded feature modules worked before and that they were not destroyed when route got inactive? If so, I know there were feature requests to destroy them leaving the route and angular team considered that option. So, are we safe assuming it will not end up being destroyed in future?